# Elasticsearch PHP Client Error - 500 unable to handle this request

Tags: php, html, elasticsearch

I was doing what [this tutorial said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xb1dHLg-Lk). Basically I have added Elasticsearch PHP client using Composer. My Elasticsearch is running on Docker on localhost:32773.

This is my index.php code. What I want to do is search through my documents in Elasticsearch and display just like in this tutorial.

```
<?php
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$hosts = [
      // Just Domain
    'http://192.168.1.101:32773',
    'http://127.0.0.1:32773'  // SSL to IP + Port
];
$clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create();   // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
$clientBuilder->setHosts($hosts);           // Set the hosts
$client = $clientBuilder->build(); 
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $query=$es->search([
        'result'=> [
            'query'=>[
            'bool' => [
            'should' => [
            'match' => ['year' => $q]],
            'match' => ['body' => $q]
            ]
            ]
            ]
        ]);
    echo'<pre>',print_r($results),'</pre>';
    if($query['hits'] ['total'] >=1) {
        $results=$query['hits'] ['hits'];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Search | ES</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <label>
        Search for something
        <input type="text" name="q">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any output. When I press search it says

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Http 500 means you have a connection but something went wrong on the server (elastic search). This could e.g. be cause by invalid request parameters not handled with a nice error by the sever or simply by invalid server config. (Have you tried to search for title instead of year as shown in the video?)

Comment: he had the title in json document. i have year too. so i chose year.

Comment: See if the server log gives you any hints

Comment: i am totally confused. My elastic search is running on dockers. then i installed this php client with composer and now it doesnt show anything. i don't know what am i doing wrong

Comment: json file looks like this
_source": {
"case_type": "Property offence",
"petition_no": 30425,
"year": 2014,
"court_name": "Lahore High Court"}

Comment: The best way to test your ElasticSearch is to run a simple query using curl , then move to the php client

Comment: Taking the advice of @Yeikel one step further, I would recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: @WayneSmallman I agree. Back in 2016 I did not know about postman

Comment: For the most part kibana is the best way to test ES